# Compare results of different php versions online

Tags: php

There is a page where you can compare results of php code in different php versions but I just can't find it. Found it on Stackoverflow some time ago. It was nice because you did not select a version. It just runs the code in all versions and compares the output.

Does someone know what page I am looking for?

Comment: http://codepad.org, http://codepad.viper-7.com?

Comment: No, you did not select a version. It just runs it in all versions. That's why it's special.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ahh, found it: http://3v4l.org

Sorry about that...